# Entity Framework not deleting existing data

Tags: entity-framework

I am new with Entity Framework. Is there a way to generate database from model without deleting existing data? Thanks.

Comment: I am confused, if you have existing data, then you have an existing database, then you are not going to generate database from model... right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use something called Migrations. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

I can recommend this tutorial. http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application